# how to check Recursively if i can create a sum from a list of numbers?

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion

How to check recursively if I can create a sum from a list or from a sublist of numbers?

```
[23, 40, 20, 6, 3, 12, 20, 21, 18, 17]
```

I can create 64 from the list `[40,6,18]`, but I can't create 34 from any sublist.

Comment: Does it need to be recursive?

Comment: This sounds like homework. What have you tried? People won't help if you have shown no effort to try it yourself. Why should we do it for you?

Comment: FYI In the general case, an exact solution to this problem is exponential in complexity. It's called the Subset Sum problem, and if you can make a polynomial time algorithm for it, then you've proved P=NP.

Answer (score 2):

To determine whether you can create a sum from a list or sublist of numbers:

1) Start with the first number.

2) If that number is equal to the sum you're trying to create, stop, you've succeeded.

3) If that number is greater than the sum you're trying to create, skip to the next number and go to step 2.

4) Subtract that number from the sum you're trying to find.

5) Repeat this algorithm, trying to find the remaining sum with the remaining numbers (those after this one).

6) Go to the next number. If there is none, stop.

7) Go to step 2.

So, for example, if you're trying to find a sum of 55 from [1, 13, 17, 8], you can reduce that to these three questions:

1. Can you find a sum of 55-1 from [13, 17, 8]? (This will find any solutions that include the first number.)
2. Can you find a sum of 55-13 from [17, 8]? (This will find any solutions that don't include the first number but do include the second.)
3. Can you find a sum of 55-17 from [8]? (This will find any solutions that don't include the first or second number but do include the third.)
4. Is 8 the solution? (This will find any solutions that don't include the first three numbers but do include the fourth.)

Notice each new question has fewer terms than the original question. So it won't go on forever.

Answer (score 1):

If this is homework, then providing a solution that isn't recursive isn't going to help you.  If it isn't homework, then don't force yourself to use recursion... use itertools instead:

```
>>> lst =[23, 40, 20, 6, 3, 12, 20, 21, 18, 17]
>>> from itertools import chain,combinations
>>> 
>>> def powerset(iterable):
...     "powerset([1,2,3]) --> () (1,) (2,) (3,) (1,2) (1,3) (2,3) (1,2,3)"
...     s = list(iterable)
...     return chain.from_iterable(combinations(s, r) for r in range(len(s)+1))
... 
>>> next(x for x in powerset(lst) if sum(x) == 64)
(23, 20, 21)
```

Comment: +1 I was experimenting with dvorak layout, it did cost me this answer. :)

Comment: I keep thinking that I should make the switch ... But it just seems so imposing.  Like, if I switch to dvorak, would I still be able to type QWERTY?  Because I don't want to lose that skill ... That said, I wouldn't mind typing faster and with less risk of injury (saying that makes me sound like an athlete)...

Comment: I don't think anyone can use both layouts efficiently at a time. I've never used dvorak before but yesterday after Martijn's suggestion I did switched to it. Now my typing speed is hardly 3-4 wpm. :D